# Spring boot report the execution status of @Async Method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm working in a spring-boot project and I have a long-running-task, that I trigger in a @Async method.

```
public void globalCall(){

  serviceOne.doSomething();
  serviceTwo.doSomething();
  serviceThree.doSomething();

}
```

and this is my async call :

```
@Async
public void longProcess(){
    //persist the status in the DB , i have a GET API to get the value from DB
   reportService.report("STARTED");

   // Trigger my long process 
   globalService.globalCall();
}
```

my issue is that I don't know at which moment I have to call `reportService.report("PROCESSING");`  when my `longProcess()` is still running ... ? the same case when i have to call `reportService.report("FINISHED");` when my `longProcess()` is finished.
do you have any idea to adjust my code in order to catch these events?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would modify your longProcess and make it synchronous, but make the call to `globalCall` the part that's async.  Also, I'd make it return a CompletableFuture that I can monitor from where I call it.

```
public void longProcess(){
    CompletableFuture<Boolean> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
    reportService.report("STARTED");

    Executors.newCachedThreadPool().submit(() -> {
        completableFuture.completeAsync(() -> {
            reportService.report("PROCESSING");

            // Trigger my long process 
            globalService.globalCall();

            reportService.report("FINISHED");

            // mark the future as finished
            return completableFuture.complete(true);
        });
    });
}
```

You would call it just as you were, but you'll get back a `CompletableFuture` that you can query if you want, but you'll have to do that in another thread, or else you'd be blocking.

Your call would look like this, identical to how you have it.  I added a means to monitor the future on the last call to give you an idea of how you can monitor it.  If you do, you'd want to run that block in its own thread otherwise, you'll be blocking.

```
public void globalCall(){
  seerviceOne.doSomething();
  serviceTwo.doSomething();

  CompletableFuture serviceThreeFuture = serviceThree.doSomething();
  // check the future every second to see if it's done, 
  while (!serviceThreeFuture.isDone()) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    reportService.report("STILL RUNNING");
  }
}
```

I would also recommend that you create an ExecutorService bean and autowire it so that you don't have to always call `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`.

```
@Bean
public ExecutorService threadPoolExecutor() {
    return Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
}
```

Use the autowired `ExecutorService` in place of `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`

```
...
@Autowired private ExcutorService executorService;

executorService.submit(() -> {
...
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. could you please show me how i can call my void globalCall() in a non blocking way

Comment: If you want to make a non-blocking call to the globalCall method, mark it as `@Async` or call it using a `Future` like the examples here show.  Your question doesn't really indicate if the method you've indicated as `globalCall()`, is the `globalService.globalCall()`.  The more real code you can add to these questions the better.

Answer (score 0):

[@lane.maxwell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/888580/lane-maxwell) give me the idea with his answer, so thank you. I was looking for a way to monitor the download of a file from a remote server to my server and then to client frontend. Also I needed to avoid timeout given that the whole process begins with an ajax call. I share my code in case it is useful to anyone:

```
//javascript functions
let intervalId;
$("#modalDownloadButton").click(function(e) {    
     e.preventDefault();
     var data = $("#modalData").val();
        
     $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: '/index/descarga2',
         headers: {  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3001/' },
         data: {data_to_server: data },            
         crossDomain: true,
         success: function(response) {
             var msgRes = response;                
             intervalId = setInterval(getFileStatus,8000,filename);
         },
         error: function(jqXHR, textStatus,errorThrown) {
             alert('Error: ' + jqXHR.status + ' - ' +textStatus +' - ' +errorThrown );
         }
     });
 });


function getFileStatus(filename) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/index/getFileStatus',
        headers: {  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3001/' },
        data: {asyncOperationId: filename },
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(response) {
            var msgRes = response;    
            var code = msgRes.split(";")[0];
            var message = msgRes.split(";")[1];
            if(code=="0"){
                $("#loader-message").empty();
                $("#loader-message").html("<p>"+message+"</p>");
            } else if (code=="9") { //error
               clearInterval(intervalId);
               intervalId = null;
               alert(message);
            } else if (code=="1") {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
                intervalId = null;
                getFileFromServer(filename);
            }

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus,errorThrown) {
            alert('Error: ' + jqXHR.status + ' - ' +textStatus +' - ' +errorThrown );
        }
    });
}


function getFileFromServer(filename) {       
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/index/getFileFromServer',
        headers: {  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3001/' },
        data: {filename: filename },
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'binary',
        success: function(response) {
            var byteArray = response;
            var loadingScreen = $("#loader-wrapper");
            loadingScreen.css("display","none");
            const blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'video/mp4' });
            const downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            const a = document.createElement("a");
            a.href = downloadUrl;
            a.download = filename;
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus,errorThrown) {
            alert('Error: ' + jqXHR.status + ' - ' +textStatus +' - ' +errorThrown );
        }
    });
}
```

Spring/Java

```
// /index/descarga2
// returns ResponseEntity<String>
launchAsyncProcess(requestUri,json,filename);
setTaskStatus(1);
String msg = "Petición lanzada. Esperando respuesta.";
log.info(msg);
return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        .contentLength(msg.length())
        .body(msg);


public void launchAsyncProcess(String uri, String json, String filename) {
    CompletableFuture<Boolean> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
    //started
    //async call    
    Executors.newCachedThreadPool().submit(() -> {
        completableFuture.completeAsync(()-> {
            setTaskStatus(2); //processing
            //calling the download process async
            requestFileForDownload(uri,json,filename);
            setTaskStatus(3); //finish
            return completableFuture.complete(true);
        });
    });
}
```

The first ajax request launches the backend process that retrieves the info and calls the download method asynchronously. The response is the initial message of the process and also launches the monitor. When the monitor receives the completion value, the file has been downloaded and can be retrieved from the server, so the last ajax request is launched to accomplish this.